# Problems constructing a datetime obj?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to make a object with the same year and month as the current date but change the day around to a different date in the month.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime


whole = date.today()
wholestr= str(whole)
vali = wholestr.split('-')
year=int(vali[0])
month=int(vali[1])
day=int(vali[2])
sub = datetime.date(year,month,16)
print sub
```

Here it says that ints work when constructing but I get an error saying that it needs a datetime.date obj and not ints.

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you call `datetime.date` when you just want to call `date` in your second to last line.  Changing to just using `date` gave me this result:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
>>> whole = date.today()
>>> wholestr = str(whole)
>>> vali = wholestr.split('-')
>>> year = int(vali[0])
>>> month = int(vali[1])
>>> day = int(vali[2])
>>> sub = date(year, month, 16)
>>> sub
datetime.date(2012, 4, 16)
>>> print sub
2012-04-16
```

Alternatively you could just call `datetime` like this:

```
>>> datetime(year, month, 16)
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 16, 0, 0)
```

Personally, this is why I always prefer to just do `import datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is pretty straightforward:

```
from datetime import [some items including] datetime
```

After the import finishes, `datetime` refers to what used to be called `datetime.datetime`, and `datetime.date` is what would otherwise be referred to as `datetime.datetime.date`.

You can either use `date` (which, since you imported it, now refers to what would otherwise be `datetime.date`) or just `import datetime` and qualify all the names, e.g., `whole = datetime.date.today()` and so on.  I prefer the latter myself because it's easy to get lost otherwise, but it's a personal preference thing.